# Partial Filling of a table with required fields in Asp.Net MVC 5 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where i am maintaining profiles of users. The profile table contains 20 columns out of which 10 are required fields. Initially when the user registers , i save that information (firstname , lastname , country , email , password ) in the default database of my project , Then i have a separate SQL database in which i am maintaining a profile for each user. The fields that i take during registration phase ( as mentioned above ) are entered into the Sql Database and leaving rest of the fields empty for later filling by the user.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Country = model.Country };

var profile = new Profile { CanID = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FName = model.FirstName, LName = model.LastName, Country = model.Country ,ProfileStatus = "0", CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

 if (result.Succeeded)
 {
      db.Profiles.Add(profile); 
      db.SaveChanges();

      //This fails because a few required fields are left out so it has to fail that i understand.

     //Also the below code has to fail because since the record is not created than how can the attach function work. 

     db.Profiles.Attach(profile);
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.CanID).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.Email).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.FName).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.LName).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.Country).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.ProfileStatus).IsModified = true;
     db.Entry(profile).Property(p => p.CreatedOn).IsModified = true;
 }
```

var user is saved into the default db of my project and var profile will be saved in the SQL Database's table with the name of Profile.

So the bottom line is , i have a table Profile , which has 20 columns out of which 10 are required , When the user initially registers  , i save that info in the default db and also i want to save it in Sql Db's Profile Table. SO how am i going to save record in Profile table when not all the required fields are filled during registration phase ? Its a create scenario to be more precise.

Comment: you will need to set your columns as nullable in the profile table, or set a default value for that records.

Comment: Why do you say they are required, yet they are not provided? Sounds like they are not required.

Comment: Actually when the user registers initially i dont want him/her to fill the whole profile page on the first go . I take minimum information while he registers , create a record for him in the table which he will must complete on his/her next login before performing any activity. So at that moment he has to fill the required fields. The table is same bt is completed in 2 steps